# How to determine the accuracy value to report from your model?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

So basically my model is based on ANN with bagging and every time I run the code on test data, I always get different accuracy values.   Like I get 33.8 % (best), 28.5 %, 26.7 % etc.  I'm pretty certain this is the result of splitting the data between train, test data each time I run the algorithm.  So my question is:  should I split the data into train, test data once before running.  Then if I run the algorithm again it would use the same train, test data.

OR should I not do this.  Namely should I just pick the best accuracy score I obtain or take an average over 100 runs.

Answer (score 0):

Try n-fold cross-validation. For example divide data into 10 sets. Train on 9 of them and test on the one omitted. Do this 10 times and average the results.